# missing part of my menu and sometimes having to much of my menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I’m making a webpage for school and ran into a problem me and my teacher can't solve. if tried allotting of things. the problem is that I copied a menu from w3schools, and it doesn't work how I wanted it to. in the first photo you see that there is some black on the top this wasn't intended and in the second photo you see that there is no black on the side this is also not intended.

https://imgur.com/user/NoahVP241

if anyone could help my fix these 2 problems it would be very much appreciated.

here is my code btw :)

**my css**

```
    @import "compass/css3";
body {
  background-image: url("background.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.headers{
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 23%;
  text-shadow:
     3px  3px 0 #000,
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
     1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px  1px 0 #000,
     1px  1px 0 #000;
  }

#ondertekst {
    position: absolute;
    left: 29%;
    top: 37%;
        font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    -webkit-animation: fill 0.5s infinite alternate;
    }
#tekst1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  margin-right: 95%;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

**My html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testhomepage.css">
<script src="testhomepage.js"></script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
<ul>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 class="headers">paul project</h1>
<p class="headers" id="ondertekst">PLAYFUL DATA-DRIVEN ACTIVE URBAN LIVING</p>
</style>
<p id="tekst1">Paul staat voor PLAYFUL DATA-DRIVEN ACTIVE URBAN LIVING en is bedoeld om mensen
  slim in beweging te krijgen. Dit word gedaan door bacons en en slimme app die je
  helpt en motiveert. In samenwerking met de gemeente Amsterdam zijn in het
  Amstelpark en het Oosterpark allerlei zendertjes geplaatst. Zogenaamde beacons.
   Daardoor kun je op bepaalde plekken speciale oefeningen doen of je wordt
   aangemoedigd met motiverende berichten.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**my js**

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by a `margin` set up the `<ul>` tag by default. Try removing any margin and padding from the `<ul>` maybe, see if that helps. It's also worth getting into the habit of using CSS normalisers (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or reseters (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Also, the descendents of a `<ul>` tag should be `<li>` tags - it might not affect the layout visually, but you should wrap your `<a>` tags in `<li>` tags to ensure compatibility and correct markup

Comment: As @Oliver says, you can add a reset or normalize css, and you can check this extra margin by using inspect element in your browser console

Answer (score 0):

The black bar at the top because the value of navbar height in javascript code smaller than the height of navbar acually

also I saw the text moves over the menu so I added z-index to be on the top

and by adding `z-index` and `left:0;` and `right:0;` this create a new position stack over the content enough to remove the white space

can you see this demo

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-75px";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.headers{
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 23%;
  text-shadow:
     3px  3px 0 #000,
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
     1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px  1px 0 #000,
     1px  1px 0 #000;
  }

#ondertekst {
    position: absolute;
    left: 29%;
    top: 37%;
        font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    -webkit-animation: fill 0.5s infinite alternate;
    }
#tekst1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  margin-right: 95%;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: -70px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  z-index:2;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 class="headers">paul project</h1>
<p class="headers" id="ondertekst">PLAYFUL DATA-DRIVEN ACTIVE URBAN LIVING</p>
</style>
<p id="tekst1">Paul staat voor PLAYFUL DATA-DRIVEN ACTIVE URBAN LIVING en is bedoeld om mensen
  slim in beweging te krijgen. Dit word gedaan door bacons en en slimme app die je
  helpt en motiveert. In samenwerking met de gemeente Amsterdam zijn in het
  Amstelpark en het Oosterpark allerlei zendertjes geplaatst. Zogenaamde beacons.
   Daardoor kun je op bepaalde plekken speciale oefeningen doen of je wordt
   aangemoedigd met motiverende berichten.
</p>
```

Comment: You could elaborate on _how_ you fixed the issues here; saying, "also white space fixed" does not convey why the problem occurred, or how it can be mitigated in the future for anyone else experiencing similar problems

Comment: @Oliver sorry I was hurry for some reasons,  I said "also white space fixed" because by adding `z-index` I created a new position stack above content so what ever the reason of white space the `left:0;` and `right:0;` will reset it

Comment: @Oliver I edited my answer to add this detials I hope this make sense for you